# How can I make this symmetric non-overlapping clock using digital Logic components?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, clock, delay, nand

How can I make a (dead-time) non overlapping symmetric clock like this with digital components such as inverters and NAND gates with 7 separate phases?
The first photo is doctored to show what I want with three phases.
Thank you in advance

[image]

This is as far as I was able to get while keeping it symmetric and non overlapping, with only two phases. I need 7

[image]

Comment: the image would be much easier to understand if the waveforms were not overlapped

Comment: I am not sure why that matters

Comment: it is hard to see the image on a smartphone display .... ascii art is also welcome by people that use a text only browser ... ----____---- ... the only description of what you are trying to achieve is the picture, so it should be as clear as possible

Comment: Sine plus 7 thresholds?